# Tess4J: Invalid memory access

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to use Tess4J in my project to extract text from an image. I am getting the following error when I try run the OCR:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access

```
    try {
        File imageFile = new File("example4.jpg");
        Tesseract instance = Tesseract.getInstance(); // JNA Interface Mapping
        //Tesseract1 instance = new Tesseract1();
        String result = instance.doOCR(imageFile);
        System.out.println(result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Bug in the native code. I suggest you report it to Tess4J.

Comment: It happen to any image or just this one?

Answer (score 12):

you can set the data path i am getting same problem when i set the data path that problem is solved
try try this

instance1.setDatapath("D://Hotel_project//Tess4J-1.2-src//Tess4J//tessdata");

Comment: Its done when project run in netbean but error occurred after run executable  jar

Answer (score 2):

You must define the datapath of the traineddata to use. If you don't specify the language it will assume it is eng.

For instance, it your project path is PROJECT and your trained data is at PROJECT/data/tessdata/eng.traineddata

```
tess.setDatapath("data");
tess.setLanguage("eng");
```

Remember that "tessdata" shoundn't be in the path you specify

Comment: what if my folder structure is `WEB-INF/classes/tessdata/eng.trainddata` ?

Comment: I'm using a project structure similar to this one, I don't know what else to do. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

if you are running on 32 bit JVM

Please try with Tesseract1 instance = new Tesseract1();

instead of using 
Tesseract instance = Tesseract.getInstance();

Comment: i try you are solution it does not work.they getting same error