# Tess4j (Tesseract V3.03) Invalid memory access

Tags: java, jna, tess4j

When invoking tesseract doOcr on a multi page tiff documents throws invalid memory access error. Datapath is set to the folder where tessdata is present and dlls are present in classes folder

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
    at com.sun.jna.Native.invokePointer(Native Method)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invokePointer(Function.java:470)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:404)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:315)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.TessBaseAPIGetUTF8Text(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.getOCRText(Tesseract.java:429)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:284)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:205)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:189)
    at Test.main(Test.java:23)
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894890/tess4j-invalid-memory-access

Comment: tried that option as well. not working when psm=ITessAPI.TessPageSegMode.PSM_AUTO is used. Works with psm = -1

Comment: This usually indicates you're passing a buffer to the native code that is invalid (might be already freed, might be too small).  Verify that all your parameters are sane when you enter `TessBaseAPIGetUTF8Text`.

Comment: Make sure your Java architecture matches your Windows architecture.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tess4J: Invalid memory access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894890/tess4j-invalid-memory-access)