# JAVA Tess4j doOCR() not working, Exception "Invalid memory access"

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, tesseract, tess4j

I'm working in dynamic web project in eclipse,
I made a  TesseractOCR class that contain:

```
public class TesseractOCR {

    public TesseractOCR()
    {
    }

    public String doOCR(String file)
    {
         System.setProperty("jna.library.path", "32".equals(System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model")) ? "lib/win32-x86" : "lib/win32-x86-64");

            File imageFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Sherein Dabbah\\Downloads\\ca096-d7a6d799d7a1d798d799d7a72.jpg");
            Tesseract instance = Tesseract.getInstance();  // JNA Interface Mapping
            Tesseract1 instance1 = new Tesseract1();
            instance.setLanguage("heb+eng");
            // Tesseract1 instance = new Tesseract1(); // JNA Direct Mapping
            // File tessDataFolder = LoadLibs.extractTessResources("tessdata"); // Maven build bundles English data
            // instance.setDatapath(tessDataFolder.getAbsolutePath());
            String sub ="";
            try {
                String result = instance.doOCR(imageFile);
                int indx1 = 6+result.indexOf("אבחנות");
                int indx2 = result.indexOf("הפניות");
                sub = result.substring(indx1,indx2-1);
                System.out.println(sub);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }

            return sub;
    }
}
```

while there's a servlet that contain function doPost()

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

         System.setProperty("jna.library.path", "32".equals(System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model")) ? "lib/win32-x86" : "lib/win32-x86-64");

         response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

            // Create path components to save the file
            final String path = "C:\\Users\\Sherein Dabbah\\Desktop\\med"; //request.getParameter("destination");
            final Part filePart = request.getPart("file");
            final String fileName = filePart.getSubmittedFileName();

            OutputStream out = null;
            InputStream filecontent = null;
            PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

            if(fileName == ""){
                writer.println("You either did not specify a file to upload or are "
                        + "trying to upload a file to a protected or nonexistent "
                        + "location.");
                return;
            }

            String fullName = path + File.separator+ fileName;

            try {
                File newFile = new File(fullName);
                out = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
                filecontent = filePart.getInputStream();

                int read = 0;
                final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

                while ((read = filecontent.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                    out.write(bytes, 0, read);
                }

                writer.println("New file " + fileName + " created at " + path);
                LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "File{0}being uploaded to {1}", 
                        new Object[]{fileName, path});

            } catch (FileNotFoundException fne) {
                writer.println("You either did not specify a file to upload or are "
                        + "trying to upload a file to a protected or nonexistent "
                        + "location.");
                writer.println("<br/> ERROR: " + fne.getMessage());

                LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Problems during file upload. Error: {0}", 
                        new Object[]{fne.getMessage()});
            } finally {
                if (out != null) {
                    out.close();
                }
                if (filecontent != null) {
                    filecontent.close();
                }
                if (writer != null) {
                    writer.close();
                }
            }

            String s = new TesseractOCR().doOCR(fullName);
            System.out.println(s);
        }
```

I have an exception:

```
   Sep 06, 2015 10:36:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
     SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [servlets.UploadServlet] in context   with path [/up] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root      cause
    java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
    at com.sun.jna.Native.invokePointer(Native Method)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invokePointer(Function.java:470)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:404)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:315)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.TessBaseAPIGetUTF8Text(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.getOCRText(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
    at classes.TesseractOCR.doOCR(TesseractOCR.java:28)
    at servlets.UploadServlet.doPost(UploadServlet.java:111) 
    at...
```

It fails at line:

```
String result = instance.doOCR(imageFile); in TesseractOCR class
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tess4J: Invalid memory access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894890/tess4j-invalid-memory-access)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably would need to call `setDatapath` to tell it where to find the `tessdata` folder for .traineddata files.

Also, you may no longer need to set `jna.library.path` variable as tess4j now can auto-extract and load the native libraries.

Comment: I was breaking my head, and this worked all of a sudden, like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

**In this case selection of language also matters -** 
I was processing image with lang=hin+eng, but it was giving the same error (mentioned in this post)

As English text was less in the image so I changed lang=hin and I got the expected result.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tesseract in = new ReadImageText().getTesseractInstance("C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/tessdata/", "hin");
        try {
            String resultText = in.doOCR(new File("C:/EA/app-result/im/01-001/34/0.png"));
            log.info("resultText {}", resultText);
        } catch (TesseractException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```