# Tess4j: Memory access error in tess4j java

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract, tess4j

I am writing a program using tess4j.jar. 
The program is extracting text and its location from within an image.
I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI1.TessBaseAPIRecognize(Native Method)
at TesseractUtility.TessBoxForLogo.run(TessBoxForLogo.java:50)
```

The funny thing is that it does not appear for every image. Does anybody know where I have an error?

Here my code:

```
public static ArrayList<Info> run(String imageName, List<String[]> wordsToFind){
    int WayToGetInfo = TessAPI1.TessPageIteratorLevel.RIL_TEXTLINE;
    wordsToFind = ParsData.addAnomalie(wordsToFind);
    //Prepare lists
    ArrayList<Info> infos = new ArrayList<Info>();
    ArrayList<Rect> rectangles = new ArrayList<Rect>();

    //Buff image
    File imageFile = new File(imageName);
    BufferedImage image = null;
    ByteBuffer buf = null;
    int w = 0;
    int h = 0;
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream(imageFile));
        w = image.getWidth();
        h = image.getHeight();

        buf = ImageIOHelper.convertImageData(image);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } 

    //Get image dimensions
    int bpp = image.getColorModel().getPixelSize();
    int bytespp = bpp / 8;
    int bytespl = (int) Math.ceil(w * bytespp);

    //Tess4 preparation
    TessBaseAPI handler = TessAPI1.TessBaseAPICreate();
    String treiningDataPath = "C:\\Users\\Karmen\\Documents\\Bitbucket\\Podjetje\\lib\\Tess4J\\tessdata";
    String lang = "slv";
    TessAPI1.TessBaseAPIInit3(handler, treiningDataPath, lang);
    TessAPI1.TessBaseAPISetPageSegMode(handler, TessAPI1.TessPageSegMode.PSM_AUTO_ONLY);
    TessAPI1.TessBaseAPISetImage(handler, buf, w, h, bytespp, bytespl);

    TessAPI1.TessBaseAPIRecognize(handler, null);

    TessResultIterator ri = TessAPI1.TessBaseAPIGetIterator(handler);
    Pointer str = TessAPI1.TessResultIteratorGetUTF8Text(ri, WayToGetInfo);
    TessAPI1.TessPageIterator pi = TessAPI1.TessResultIteratorGetPageIterator(ri);
    TessAPI1.TessPageIteratorBegin(pi);

    //Iterate thru rows
    while (TessAPI1.TessPageIteratorNext(pi,WayToGetInfo) == TessAPI1.TRUE){
        str = TessAPI1.TessResultIteratorGetUTF8Text(ri, WayToGetInfo);
        if (str!=null){
            float confidence = TessAPI1.TessResultIteratorConfidence(ri, WayToGetInfo);
            String word = str.getString(0);
            IntBuffer leftB = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
            IntBuffer topB = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
            IntBuffer rightB = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
            IntBuffer bottomB = IntBuffer.allocate(1);

            TessAPI1.TessPageIteratorBoundingBox(pi, WayToGetInfo, leftB, topB, rightB, bottomB);
            int left = leftB.get();
            int top = topB.get();
            int right = rightB.get();
            int bottom = bottomB.get();
            Rect rectangle1 = new Rect((int) (left-0.05*left), 
                                       (int) (top-0.05*top), 
                                       (int) ((right+0.05*right)-(left-0.05*left)),
                                       (int) ((bottom+0.5*bottom)-(top-0.05*top)));
            rectangles.add(rectangle1);

            String kword = "";
            for (String[] s:wordsToFind){
                //System.out.println(s[1]);
                if (word.toLowerCase().contains(s[1].toLowerCase())
                        ){
                    Rect rect = new Rect(left, top, right-left,bottom-top);
                    infos.add(copmare(word, s, rect, confidence));
                    kword = s[0];
                }
            }       
        }
    }
    draw(imageName, rectangles);
    return infos;   
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might benefit from using a good debugging tool or technique. With a debugging tool, you can step through your code line by line and see what it's doing. Or, you can use certain techniques, such as adding print statements or alerts, to trace your program's execution without a debugger. More helpful info here: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Make sure your Java architecture matches your Windows architecture.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tess4J: Invalid memory access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894890/tess4j-invalid-memory-access)

Answer (score 1):

Convert your image to gray scale before running through tesseract

Answer (score 0):

That exception is usually due to Tesseract being unable to find `tessdata` folder. The datapath should be set to the parent of that folder.

```
String treiningDataPath = "C:\\Users\\Karmen\\Documents\\Bitbucket\\Podjetje\\lib\\Tess4J\\";
```

Comment: Thx @nguyenq for answer... that however does not resolve my problem... and it would appear for every image, I presume. It how ever appear for some of them although they appear to be the same according to data.

Comment: Make sure your Java architecture matches your Windows architecture.