# Java code working fine when created as an independent static main class, but not when called from servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, tesseract, tess4j

I am using Tess4j API for performing OCR and have created a dynamic web project in eclipse. If I create a new java class directly under the Java resources folder, the code is working fine.

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
        File image = new File("Scan0008.jpg");  
        ITesseract instance = new Tesseract();
        try{
            String result = instance.doOCR(image);
            System.out.println(result);
        }catch(TesseractException e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

However I am getting an exception when I am calling the same code from my Servlets doPost method.

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            Validate valObj = new Validate();
            valObj.validate();
    }
    public void validate() {
        File image = new File("Scan0008.jpg");
        ITesseract instance = new Tesseract();
        try {
            String result = instance.doOCR(image);
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (TesseractException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I have included all the required jars under lib folder of WEB-INF. Have also added the jars in the projects build path. Could anyone please let me know what I am doing wrong.
Exception  : 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input not set
23:33:45.002 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] ERROR net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract - Input not set
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input not set

Comment: Please [format your post](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). This is a mess and won't get read in its current form.

Comment: Are you certain the servlet version is finding the specified file? Try adding an output after the `File image = ...` to ensure the file exists and is readable.

Comment: @KevinO .. Just added a System.out.println() after the File image = .. line and it outputs on the screen..so i think the file is readable

Comment: please print image.exists(). if this not exist, it will not throw exception, but exists() method will return false.

Comment: @SaurabhGour, `new File(some_file)` does **not** throw an exception if the file is not at the expected location. Just printing something doesn't help. You should **explicitly** check `if (! image.exists()) { display error }`.

Comment: @KevinO ..The image was not readable..Now i have given the absolute path but getting another exception java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access

Comment: please update your question or post a new question, and please use formatting.

Comment: Hi @KevinO..thank you..changing the image path to absolute worked !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your current directory is different when you are calling from servlet. the current directory is you tomcat bin folder. so when you are calling like this:

```
File image = new File("Scan0008.jpg");
```

your scan0008.jpg must be put in bin folder of tomcat or you must use absolute path of your file.

Comment: I've also tried giving the absolute path..but it does not work..still getting the exception. File seems to be readable

Comment: please check image.exists() to see if it exists

Comment: Hi Mojtaba, it does not exist. I have tried giving the absolute path..now image is readable.. but now I am getting this exception : <java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access

Comment: Yes, that must work, you may type it incorrectly. please check your absolute address

Comment: Hi Mojtaba..the other exception got solved from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894890/tess4j-invyalid-memory-access.. Thank  you for your time :)