# Tesseract: Error when read non-English text on image

Tags: java, tesseract, tess4j

I am extracting non-English text from image(bill) by using Tesseract

But I met an Error when I executed function doOCR(BufferedImage var1) (No error if set English language) :

```
contains_unichar_id(unichar_id):Error:Assert failed:in file c:\projects\github\tesseract-ocr\src\ccutil\unicharset.h, line 511
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
    at com.sun.jna.Native.invokePointer(Native Method)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invokePointer(Function.java:470)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:404)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:315)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.TessBaseAPIGetUTF8Text(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.getOCRText(Tesseract.java:433)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:288)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:260)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:241)
```

My code:

```
ITesseract iT = new Tesseract();
iT.setLanguage(LANGUAGE);
iT.setDatapath(System.getenv("TESSDATA_PREFIX"));
try {
  return iT.doOCR(bufferedImage);
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.getMessage();
  return "Error while reading image";
}
```

Some bills can extract successfully. But with some special cases, I faced that error.

Comment: This question needs details. Provide an example, please. See [ask]

Comment: Have you checked this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894890/tess4j-invalid-memory-access

Comment: @Batu.Khan I set the datapath but It doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my issue. In file pom.xml, I changed from:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
  <version>5.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```